# How can I retrieve my Let's Encrypt registration's current email address?

Tags: linux, lets-encrypt, certbot

I understand that *Let's Encrypt* maintains an email address as a registration and recovery contact for every "account."  This email address is used to [notify the owner of the certificates of upcoming expirations](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/expiration-emails) as well as [warn of other problems with the certificate](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/2020-02-29-caa-rechecking-bug/114591).

I have inherited several websites that use *Let's Encrypt* and wish to determine what (if any) registration and recovery contact email is configured for these sites.  Unfortunately I find no documented means of doing so.

Several suggestions indicate the email address is stored at `/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/*/regr.json`, but apparently this was only the case with earlier releases of `certbot`.

Answer (score 2):

Here I [answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/):

It turns out that, at least as of certbot version 0.26.1, the following command both updates my *Let's Encrypt* registration and recovery contact ***and reports the previous contact in Let's Encrypt's debug log***:

`certbot register --update-registration --email <your-email-address>`

In my case, after running the above command the debug log (`/var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log`) contained a report like:

```
2020-03-05 14:05:17,060:DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /acme/new-acct HTTP/1.1" 200 575
2020-03-05 14:05:17,060:DEBUG:acme.client:Received response:...
{
...
  "contact": [
    "mailto:<previous support email>"
  ],
...
  "createdAt": "<when previous support email was created>",
...
}
```

This allowed me to retrieve not only the previous support email address but also when it was configured, even though that information was not listed in `/etc/letsencrypt/accounts/acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory/*/regr.json`